# Automate keystrokes in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, script

I need to automate the pressing of the  key then pressing 5 digits then press  in Windows 7 64-bit.  I have an app that comes up on the screen and I need the "script" to press the keys.  I don't even need mouse support.  What can I use to do this?  Any examples or links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest Autohotkey, it is more popular and it provides very simple script writing style. There are 64 bit version too, therefore you can find a lot of useful scripts in Autohotkey.

> www.autohotkey.com

Answer (score 3):

I would look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) first.  Probably that's all you'll need.